# Google maps URL: is it possible to combine query and map options?

Tags: api, google-maps, url

I want to search for coordinates, display the marker, switch to satellite (and optionally tilt the view, north aligned at 45 degrees). Example: https://goo.gl/maps/H1SFmN9un582

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide lists the available URL parameters, but they're split into sections (search, directions, map, streetview). When I try to use the map parameters in the search and vice versa, they're ignored. The best I can manage is centering the map to the coordinates, but then the pin is missing:

https://www.google.com/maps/@?api=1&map_action=map&center=48.792260,9.232073&zoom=18&basemap=satellite

Answer (score 0):

From the bellow script you can get lat and log then easily find point

```js
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Using the scripts in web pages</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script defer src="//cdn.rawgit.com/chrisveness/geodesy/v1.1.2/latlon-spherical.js"></script>
    <script defer src="//cdn.rawgit.com/chrisveness/geodesy/v1.1.2/dms.js"></script>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            document.querySelector('#calc-dist').onclick = function() {
                const lat1 = document.querySelector('#lat1').value;
                const lon1 = document.querySelector('#lon1').value;
                const lat2 = document.querySelector('#lat2').value;
                const lon2 = document.querySelector('#lon2').value;
                const p1 = new LatLon(Dms.parseDMS(lat1), Dms.parseDMS(lon1));
                const p2 = new LatLon(Dms.parseDMS(lat2), Dms.parseDMS(lon2));
                const dist = parseFloat(p1.distanceTo(p2).toPrecision(4));
                document.querySelector('#result-distance').textContent = dist;
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        Lat 1: <input type="text" name="lat1" id="lat1">
        Lon 1: <input type="text" name="lon1" id="lon1">
        Lat 2: <input type="text" name="lat2" id="lat2">
        Lon 2: <input type="text" name="lon2" id="lon2">
        <button type="button" id="calc-dist">Calculate distance</button>
        <output id="result-distance"></output> metres
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```